# Trying to compare classes of different elements

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to find a way to check if classes in an element matches those in another element. I have tried using code below:

Using dataset seems to work, however, I'm looking to explore the possibility of doing this through pure Javascript. The line that works is commented out (var matches = first.dataset.name === second.dataset.name;) and the line that I'm having difficulty getting to work is (var matches = first.classList === second.classList;)

javascript:

```
//check for 2 matching squares
function checkIfMatches() {

  //var matches = first.dataset.name === second.dataset.name;
  var matches = first.classList === second.classList;
  matches ? disable() : unflip();

}
```

html:

```
<li class="card">
   <i class="pa pa-test"></i>
</li>

<li class="card">
   <i class="pa pa-test"></i>
</li>
```

Thanks for any help. If more details are needed you can comment.

Comment: `classList` is an object, it's not going to be the same between two element,.  You could maybe try `classList.value` instead.  Although do take note if you had a class as  `class1 class2`  & `class2 class1`, it would still be false, when you might want it to be true.

Answer (score 3):

Use *Array spread* `[...classList]` to make the `classList` an `Array`, then check if every member is contained in the `classList` of the other using `Array.prototype.every()`.

```js
function sameClassList({classList: x},{classList: y}) {
  return [...x].every(z=>y.contains(z)) 
    && [...y].every(z=>x.contains(z));
}

console.log(sameClassList(a,b)); // true
console.log(sameClassList(a,c)); // false
console.log(sameClassList(b,c)); // false
```

```html
<div class="foo bar" id="a"></div>
<div class="bar foo" id="b"></div>
<div class="foo bar baz" id="c"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comments into account, this solves it independently of the order.
Changed the example a bit, so it could be executed.

```js
//check for 2 matching squares
function checkIfMatches() {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('card')
  var first = elements[0].getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
  var second = elements[1].getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
  var matches = first.classList.length === second.classList.length
  first.classList.forEach(entry => matches = matches && second.classList.contains(entry))
  console.log(matches)
  
  // matches ? disable() : unflip();

}

checkIfMatches()
```

```html
<li class="card">
   <i class="pa pa-test"></i>
</li>

<li class="card">
   <i class="pa pa-test"></i>
</li>
```